# Why does my VBA code keep hanging?

Tags: vba, excel, loops, debugging, encoding

I attached two links to a flowchart of how the VBA code should go about, and a screenshot of my two sheets.

[image]

[image: image2]

Basically, I have two sheets - "Disbursements" & "Cheque Info". On the Disbursements' sheet, I need to consider only the rows with count > 1 (column I). For example, I won't consider row 8 of column I, but will consider row 12. Every row that has a count of > 1 should have a value on row H by the end of the run. 
After considering which row has a count >1, we check if the corresponding amount (column F) is equal to Cheque Info's column E. Then if for example, for row 12 of disbursements, 1,384.35 is equal to row 9 of Cheque Info. We must get the difference of these dates then store it to a variable "Current". But there are many "1,384.35" that we must get the minimum difference for the dates, thus a need for a loop.

Again, I need to do loops for each row that has a count of >1 on disbursements' column I, so that I will get the date on Cheque Info (with the same amount) that has a minimum gap from the date on Disbursements sheet. For example, the date that has the least gap for 1/18/2016 (for the amount 1,384.35) is 1/4/2016.

Here is my current code:

```
Sub F110Loop()

Dim x As Integer 'current amount
Dim y As Integer
Dim d As Double 'delta between Disbursement date and Cheque Release date
Dim Current As Integer
Dim Least As Integer
Dim Dis As Worksheet
Dim Cheque As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set Dis = wb.Sheets("Disbursements")
Set Cheque = wb.Sheets("Cheque Info")
wb.Activate

For x = 4 To 600
    Do While Dis.Cells(x, 9).Value > 1
        'IF same amount, get row number to get corresponding date, reference that date
        For y = 3 To 600
            If Dis.Cells(x, 6).Value = Cheque.Cells(y, 5).Value Then
                'THEN get delta
                Current = Dis.Cells(x, 4).Value -Cheque.Cells(y, 2)
                'IF current is less than the least delta
            ElseIf Current < Least Then
                'THEN update new value of delta
                Current = Least
            Else
                'copy paste the date (from the least delta row)
                Cheque.Cells(y, 2).Copy Destination:=Dis.Cells(x, 8)
            End If
        Next y
    Loop
Next x

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code hangs because you dont have any check s for null/vbnullstring or 0 values. i.e.:

```
IF Dis.Cells(x,6).Value <> vbNullString OR Dis.Cells(x,6).Value <> 0 Then....
```

reason this is needed is to keep excle from looping through each cell till out of memory...

Answer (score 0):

Your `Do While`loop is an infinite loop. Once it catches a cell such that `Dis.Cells(x, 9).Value > 1` it will loop forever, because inside the loop, nothing will change, neither `x` nor `Dis.Cells(x, 9).Value`.

I think you have to think again the logic of the subroutine. Maybe replacing that loop with a simple `IF` test would do.

Answer (score 0):

The `Do Loop` will not exit until `Dis.Cells(x, 9).Value > 1`.  Inside the `Do Loop` you change values in `Dis.Cells(x, 8)`.  If `Dis.Range("I3:I600")` does not have formulas in it or if anyone of the cells in `Dis.Cells(x, 9).Value never exceed1 then the`Do Loop` will never exit.

```
Do While Dis.Cells(x, 9).Value > 1
    'IF same amount, get row number to get corresponding date, reference that date
    For y = 3 To 600

    Next y
Loop
```

You should also turn off `ScreenUpdating` while the code is running.  If you don't need any formulas to recalculate then set `Calculation` to `xlCalculationManual`.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

Why are you using `Range.Copy`?

```
Cheque.Cells(y, 2).Copy Destination:=Dis.Cells(x, 8)
```

A direct assignment is much more effecient

```
Dis.Cells(x, 8) = Cheque.Cells(y, 2)
```

If there are no formula that you need to recalculate then using an array instead should cut you execution time to under 1 second.

Comment: Thank you so much @thomas inzina :)